# UICollectionView doesn't call delegate methods

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've setup a `UICollectionView` in a storyboard and connected the dataSource and delegate outlets. I've registered a cell via nib which I dequeue in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method.

All works perfectly expect that the delegate methods are never called. For example: When touching on a cell, I expect the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` to be called.

I've double-checked the delegate of the collection view - it's assigned correctly.

Does anybody know the reason why the methods are not called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's completely my fault. I've added a transparent subview to the front which consumes the touches - a really bad mistake.